# Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running cordova.sh Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I followed the instructions on https://www.meteor.com/try/7 in order to properly install the android sdk for meteor. Although I was able to properly install it, I can't get it to work.

When trying to start the android emulator using `meteor run android` it throws me an exception:

> Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running cordova.sh
>   Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

**Edit**

The same applies to the ios simulator when trying to run it using `meteor run ios`

Comment: did you follow also try/1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need go to your directory first and run the command.

```
cd your_cordova_project_path
```